# Running applications not showing up in the dash

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, activities-overview

I am running Ubuntu Cosmic (18.10) and I noticed that various running applications (not all of them) are not showing up in the dash when running. It is the case for Rhythmbox, Document viewer, Shotwell, etc.

This screenshot shows it: there are various running apps not present in the dash (or the dock at the left):
[image: ScreenShot of the desktop]

Could someone help me solve the issue?

Comment: Very strange! What happens if you restart GNOME shell by pressing <Alt><F2>, then entering `r` and finally pressing <Enter>?

Comment: Same problem on a fresh install of 18.04 LTS. It seems so far that restarting Gnome fixed the problem. Thanks @pomsky

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some icons and text randomly become invisible after waking up from sleep (Ubuntu GNOME)](https://askubuntu.com/q/764361/)