# GNOME Dash-to-dock feature not show running apps

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-dash

It shows the favorite applications, and properly shows the orange dotd on the left of the running ones, but not the running ones if they are not favorites.

From dconf-editor, org->gnome->shell->extensions->dash-to-dock->show-running is set to on. In the picture it is possible to see the options in dconf and the behavior of the dock:

[image: picture]

neither the terminal nor dconf-editor are visible in the dock. The applications are normally visible elsewhere (for example clicking on Activities).

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Restarting GNOME shell (by pressing <Alt><F2>, then entering `r` and finally pressing <Enter>) would probably solve the issue temporarily.

Comment: You are right, it did, thanks a lot! Is it a known bug? It there a permanent solution?

Comment: Similar question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107733/running-applications-not-showing-up-in-the-dash

Answer (score 1):

I also use [`Dash to Dock`](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) gnome extension, so I was able to fix this by disabling `Use built-in theme` in the Apperance section:

[image]

After doing this, the indicators were now showing up

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have multiple monitors attached to my laptop and every time I was clicking on nautilus it was opening up a new window and was not showing the little orange running dot that Ubuntu shows for running instance of the program.

I managed to solve this by turning off "isolate-monitors" flag in dconf-editor, /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/isolate-monitors

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had "Use builtin theme" disabled already as per the above answer, but running applications still were not showing.

I enabled and disabled "Use builtin theme", and now the running applications are showing. Even when I *re-enable* "Use builtin theme" the Running Applications are showing.

Perhaps the bug is that you have to change *something* in the config for it to work.

Created bug in dash-to-dock:

https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/1221