# Dock does not update when launching applications

Tags: icons, 20.10, dock, dconf

I have customize the dock in Ubuntu 20.10 with dconf-editor and the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position BOTTOM
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode FIXED
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock unity-backlit-items true
```

After that customization, when I launch an application, its icon doesn't appear in the dock. This is an example with Ubuntu Software application:

[image: Example]

What could be the reason?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/1221) that has been around for at least a year. There seem to be two solutions.

**Solution from the Bug Report:**

1. Right click dock and go to Dash To Dock Settings
2. Enable or disable "Use bulitin theme"
3. Dash to dock now shows running applications

**Solution from [Same Question in 2019](https://askubuntu.com/q/1111630/1091774):**

Restart Gnome by:

1. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Entering `r` into the textbox
3. Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Hopefully one of these options will work for you until the bug is fixed in Dash to Dock.